# handling exception messages in jsf

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

i have a servlet filter which controls if my web application is started normally;

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest aReq, ServletResponse aResponse, FilterChain aChain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) aReq;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) aResponse;


        if(!myContext.isSystemReady())
        {
            // SHOW AN ERROR PAGE WITH SOME EXCEPTION MESSAGE
        }

        aChain.doFilter(request, aResponse);
        return;

    }
```

what is the best way to show error messages in this style?

- if i use

  request.setAttribute("errMsj", "System not ready. Contact your web administrator");

how can i show it in my jsf page?

```
ERROR !<br />
detailed message is: <h:outputText value="errMsj HERE!"></h:outputText>
```

- or should i use a ststusbean to show error messages? in this time i should access facescontext in filter and write error msg to that bean. may there be a problem with it?
- or any better ideas?

(using jsf2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to a specific error page by defining a `web-app/error-page` element in your `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Check the [schema](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd), there are more features (like reacting to specific exception classes).

Me peronally, I'd just throw an exception in `doFilter` (having full exception stack trace may be critical).
The exception can later on be retrieved as `#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}` if you want error page to be JSF page.